# SVN: merge specific revision of trunk into branch

Tags: svn, version-control, merge

I have an SVN repository where I created a branch.  A coworker made a change on the trunk that conflicts with the changes I made on my branch.  Unfortunately, SVN does a bad job with the merge conflict (it marks differences in places where they shouldn't be).  I know the conflicts arise from revision #100 and that the previous trunk revision is #99.  I would like to merge revision #99 on the trunk into my branch (including all the changes to the trunk since the last time I did such a merge).  Then I want to more carefully work on the merge from revision #100 to my trunk.

Normally I would go to my local copy of the branch, then merge with the command

```
svn merge ^/reponame/trunk/directory .
```

But that merges the latest revision of the trunk (which would be #100).  What would be the command to instead merge revision #99 from the trunk into my branch?

Answer (score 2):

A combination of Google and trying things that didn't work resulted in the following method:

1. In my local checkout of the branch:

   svn mergeinfo --show-revs eligible ^/reponame/trunk/directory .

   which gave me the list of revisions on the trunk that hadn't yet been merged into my branch.
2. For each of those revision numbers:

   svn merge -c #### ^/reponame/trunk/directory .

   which lets me (one revision at a time) merge changes from the trunk into my branch.

I'm reasonably confident that there are better ways, but this was functional.